# Avoid diamond problem in abstract + concrete class hierarchies

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, class-hierarchy, diamond-problem

I am working on a game and we want to wrap the physics engine so it can easily be exchanged.

So we want to create an abstract class hierarchy as a template, specifying everything the engine has to support and working as an interface for the rest of the game. Then we want to create concrete classes, implementing those abstract classes and wrapping the actual engine. The problem is that this creates a lot of diamonds, for example:

[image: example of a diamond problem]

Where Shape and Circle contain engine-independent functionality but also some engine-dependent abstract methods and P2Shape and P2Circle are wrappers for the P2 engine and implement those engine-specific methods. And from a broader perspective, we don't just have these two classes but a whole hierarchy tree of (not purely) abstract template classes and a whole hierarchy tree of concrete implementations. Each of the concrete classes "is-a" -> its abstract template and "is-a" -> its base class in the hierarchy:

[image: diamonds in abstract + concrete hierarchy trees]

We are probably not the first people to encounter this problem and this is probably some symptom of bad design, so I am curious about the proper way to implement this. To make it a bit more interesting, we are working in TypeScript which does not support multiple inheritance.

Here are the approaches I considered:

1. Favor composition over inheritance

Let's say a Shape has a position and a Circle has a radius. In my opinion, a Circle clearly "is a" Shape that has a position and a radius, it doesn't "have a" radius and a shape that has a position. Also, if I access the position I don't want to say myCircle.shape.position. Shapes are a textbook example of inheritance hierarchies. The other option would be that a Shape has a P2Shape but then all engine-specific stuff has to be squeezed in there and the type of the field has to be any or generic. Or a P2Shape has a Shape but then the rest of the game cannot work with it because it is unaware of the P2Shape type.

2. Use interfaces instead of abstract classes

TypeScript supports a separate concept of interfaces where multiple inheritance and the diamond problem are not an issue. But there we cannot put any implementation whatsoever into the engine-independent parts.

3. Mixins

I feel like the concept of mixins is to create a set of modular and reusable components that can be combined into classes that make use of the functionality. In our case that would mean that P2Shape and Circle are modular components and P2Circle uses them. That somehow doesn't feel semantically right to me.

All three solutions feel somewhat unsatisfying. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious what engine-specific stuff is implemented in Shape and P2Shape. IMO, a shape is just a shape in the geometric sense, i.e. has some way to describe its points, sides, borders, area, etc. It sounds like in your example it's more of a "GameEntity", which sounds like a better fit for composition, i.e. a GameEntity contains a shape interface implementation and a position. If there is shape-specific logic that needs to be implemented for each engine, then you can go more granular than mixins and implement individual functions, which can also be accepted by a GameEntity.

Comment: I won't mark it as such because I think the question is not completely OT, but it it better suited for [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). To my understanding, multiple inheritance was deliberately not implemented in a lot of OO languages precisely to avoid the diamond problem as it can easily lead to a lot of headaches and undefined behaviour (e.g. if P2Shape and Circle implement the same method, which one does P2Circle use).

Comment: Those languages (such as Typescript), provide interfaces precisely to enable "is-a" merging, while keeping `extends` one directional only for cases when the behaviour of X strongly depend on their parent. As for how this could be alternatively designed, my 2 cents is: make one line of inheritance, the one that is more strongly coupled, while making the other one interfaces and creating a different "layer" of the app (probably a collection of static methods in an abstract class) that contains methods that handle the more generic interfaces, which you may partially use in your "end class"